# iOS - Disable Scrolling when Editing Text Field

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am trying to disable the scrolling (and preferably all background touches) when editing a uitextfiled.

Here is the scenario:

I have a ScrollView setup with several text fields.  Upon editing a text field I animate the view up/down so that the text field will sit just above where the keyboard/keypad will appear.  In the case where I changed the keyboard style to phone/number pad I have a subview setup with a done button available to dismiss the keyboard when editing is done.  All of the animation works as expected.  However, the user is able to scroll the background and select other fields.  I would like to disable this functionality so that all they can do is view what is shown on the screen and edit the one field.

I've tried doing the [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO] which locks the scroll view in place, however the keyboard is not available to type information into the text field.  Again in the cases where the keyboard is set to phone/number pad my subview appears, just no keyboard.

I have also tried setting the textfield being edited as the first responder but that seems to mess up the view entirely, probably due to my animation of the view subview.

Is there a way for me to still animate the view the way I want and disable the scrolling of the scroll view, or all background touches in that view entirely?

Comment: Have you tried disabling scrolling in `didBeginEditing`?

Comment: I have not tried this but will give it a shot.

Comment: I did try adding the disabling scrolling into the didBeginEditing, but that did not work.  The scroll view locks as expected, but the keyboard is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Make your viewController the delegate of the textField and in the `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` disable the scrolling.. `self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;` and in the - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField set the scrolling enabled again...

You can also disable all the other textfields as your requirement states.

```
self.otherTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Hoping this helps.

Comment: Ankit,   I tried what you suggested and I understand what is going on there, however I did make a mistake when stating I wanted to disable other text fields.  I actually need to disable all buttons/options on the screen.

In everything posted the [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO] provides the exact functionality I am looking for. The issue I am having with using this method is on text fields.  When I click on a text field and on the didBeginEditing method I do the [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO] the keyboard is not visible.  Is there a way to use that call and have the keyboard visible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO
```

?

Comment: I did, but the user is still able to select other fields on the screen. I was trying to avoid this as well.

Comment: As Ankit said, self.otherTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;